# must match both columns in boolean mode

Tags: mysql

I have this sql query currently:

```
SELECT htext FROM paragraphs WHERE MATCH(htext, keywords)
AGAINST('+genomics' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY MATCH(htext)
AGAINST('+genomics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)desc
```

however I'm getting back rows if they match in EITHER htext OR keywords...I want the keyword to have to match in htext AND keywords. Im also having issues actually ordering by relevance in mysql 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT htext,  MATCH(htext) AGAINST('+genomics' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance FROM paragraphs 
WHERE MATCH(htext) AGAINST('+genomics' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND MATCH(keywords) AGAINST('+genomics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
```